What does it mean to take the transpose of a matrix representing a system of linear equations?
For instance, consider the system
$x+y+z=1
\\
2x+3y+z=2$
which is say
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
2&3&1
\end{bmatrix}$
now , taking its transpose
$A^T=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\
1&3\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}$
Now unlike the first matrix, adding rows doesn't help us as they represent  the coefficients of  equations in different variables. So for a system of linear equations, does taking the transpose have any meaning at all?

Yes. The nullspace of that matrix gives you constraints a vector $b$ must satisfy in order for $Ax=b$ to be consistent. In your case, there are no constraints.

Thanks!What's a null space? The null matrix?

null space is ${\mathbf{x}:A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}}$

"$A^T$ describes the transpose of that linear map with respect to the dual bases."
